# Synchronizing access to a doubly-linked list

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a (special kind of) doubly-linked list in C, in a pthreads environment but using only C-wrapped synchronization instructions like atomic CAS, etc. rather than pthread primitives. (The elements of the list are fixed-size chunks of memory and almost surely cannot fit `pthread_mutex_t` etc. inside them.) I don't actually need full arbitrary doubly-linked list methods, only:

- insertion at the end of the list
- deletion from the beginning of the list
- deletion at arbitrary points in the list based on a pointer to the member to be removed, which was obtained from a source other than by traversing the list.

So perhaps a better way to describe this data structure would be a queue/fifo with the possibility of removing items mid-queue.

Is there a standard approach to synchronizing this? I'm getting stuck on possible deadlock issues, some of which are probably inherent to the algorithms involved and others of which might stem from the fact that I'm trying to work in a confined space with other constraints on what I can do.

**Edit**: In particular, I'm stuck on what to do if adjacent objects are to be removed simultaneously. Presumably when removing an object, you need to obtain locks on both the previous and next objects in the list and update their next/prev pointers to point to one another. But if either neighbor is already locked, this would result in a deadlock. I've tried to work out a way that any/all of the removals taking place could walk the locked part of the list and determine the maximal sublist that's currently in the process of removal, then lock the nodes adjacent to that sublist so that the whole sublist gets removed as a whole, but my head is starting to hurt.. :-P

**Conclusion(?)**: To follow up, I do have some code I want to get working, but I'm also interested in the theoretical problem. Everyone's answers have been quite helpful, and combined with details of the constraints outside what I expressed here (you *really* don't want to know where the pointer-to-element-to-be-removed came from and the synchronization involved there!) I've decided to abandon the local-lock code for now and focus on:

- using a larger number of smaller lists which each have individual locks.
- minimizing the number of instructions over which locks are held and poking at memory (in a safe way) prior to acquiring a lock to reduce the possibility of page faults and cache misses while a lock is held.
- measuring the contention under artificially-high load and evaluating whether this approach is satisfactory.

Thanks again to everybody who gave answers. If my experiment doesn't go well I might come back to the approaches outlined (especially Vlad's) and try again.

Comment: I believe that you can do it with a double-linked list as long as you don't care about list consistency. The object being added or removed may be visible or not depending on which direction you are moving on the list.

Comment: @R: a fixed-length buffer (used circularly) is no good to you?

Comment: Sadly, I can't find a way to make it work with a fixed-length circular buffer. I've wanted to from the beginning because it would be so much simpler and perform so much better...

Comment: @R: do you mean that you can't find a way to make a lock-free fixed-length circular buffer work, or that you can't find a way to make such a buffer satisfy your application's needs?

Comment: I can't find a way to make it satisfy the requirements. I'd need a way to ensure in advance that the circular buffer has already been sufficiently enlarged to satisfy all possible future insertions up to the next point where memory reallocation will become possible (it's not possible at the point of insertion).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_compare-and-swap

Answer (score 8):

Why not just apply a coarse-grained lock? Just lock the whole queue.

A more elaborate (however not necessarily more efficient, depends on your usage pattern) solution would be using a read-wrote lock, for reading and writing, respectively.

---

Using lock-free operations seem to me not a very good idea for your case. Imagine that some thread is traversing your queue, and at the same moment the "current" item is deleted. Doesn't matter how many additional links your traverse algorithm holds, all that items may be deleted, so your code would have no chance to finish the traversal.

---

Another issue with compare-and-swap is that with pointers you never know whether it really points to the same old structure, or the old structure has been freed and some new structure is allocated at the same address. This may or may not be an issue for your algorithms.

---

For the case of "local" locking (i.e., the possibility to lock each list item separately), An idea would be to make the locks ordered. Ordering the locks ensures the impossibility of a deadlock. So your operations are like that:

Delete by the pointer p to the **previous** item:

1. lock p, check (using perhaps special flag in the item) that the item is still in the list
2. lock p->next, check that it's not zero and in the list; this way you ensure that the p->next->next won't be removed in the meantime
3. lock p->next->next
4. set a flag in p->next indicating that it's not in the list
5. (p->next->next->prev, p->next->prev) = (p, null); (p->next, p->next->next) = (p->next->next, null)
6. release the locks

Insert into the beginning:

1. lock head
2. set the flag in the new item indicating that it's in the list
3. lock the new item
4. lock head->next
5. (head->next->prev, new->prev) = (new, head); (new->next, head) = (head, new)
6. release the locks

This seems to be correct, I didn't however try this idea.

Essentially, this makes the double-linked list work as if it were a single-linked list.

---

If you don't have the pointer to the previous list element (which is of course usually the case, as it's virtually impossible to keep such a pointer in consistent state), you can do the following:

Delete by the pointer c to the item to be deleted:

1. lock c, check if it is still a part of the list (this has to be a flag in the list item), if not, operation fails
2. obtain pointer p = c->prev
3. unlock c (now, c may be moved or deleted by other thread, p may be moved or deleted from the list as well) [in order to avoid the deallocation of c, you need to have something like shared pointer or at least a kind of refcounting for list items here]
4. lock p
5. check if p is a part of the list (it could be deleted after step 3); if not, unlock p and restart from the beginning
6. check if p->next equals c, if not, unlock p and restart from the beginning [here we can maybe optimize out the restart, not sure ATM]
7. lock p->next; here you can be sure that p->next==c and is not deleted, because the deletion of c would have required locking of p
8. lock p->next->next; now all the locks are taken, so we can proceed
9. set the flag that c is not a part of the list
10. perform the customary (p->next, c->next, c->prev, c->next->prev) = (c->next, null, null, p)
11. release all the locks

Note that just having a pointer to some list item cannot ensure that the item is not deallocated, so you'll need to have a kind of refcounting, so that the item is not destroyed at the very moment you try to lock it.

---

Note that in the last algorithm the number of retries is bounded. Indeed, new items cannot appear on the left of c (insertion is at the rightmost position). If our step 5 fails and thus we need a retry, this can be caused only by having p removed from the list in the meanwhile. Such a removal can occur not more than N-1 times, where N is the initial position of c in the list. Of course, this worst case is rather unlikely to happen.

Comment: "Traversing the list" is not an operation on my linked list. The only options are insertion at one end, removal from the other, and removal based on a pointer to an element obtained from another source (not from traversing the list).

Comment: Course-grained lock? It would mean near-constant contention under high loads instead of essentially-zero contention. Lock-free operations? Sorry, I wasn't clear; SWAP/CAS/etc. could simply be used to implement small spinlocks rather than for lock-free if it works better. CAS ABA issues - probably not relevant here but I need to make sure.

Comment: Re: contention - how many threads do you expect to have hitting this list? Is the unlink operation (only a handful of instructions, after all) really going to take so much time (compared to the other work the threads are doing, outside the lock) that contention for a list-wide lock would become an issue?

Comment: @Vlad: Thanks. A variant on the second *might* work. One issue is that before this begins, I have a lock on the current node (the one to be removed) which I cannot release for other reasons. The problem seems to be that I'm trying to use this same lock for 2 separate things. If I make a separate lock bit (yes, sadly I only have room for bits..) for the node as a member of the linked list, and designate the existing lock to only apply to the node's other existing roles, I think your algorithm may work.

Comment: @R..: note that my implementation satisfies the @Adam's idea. Lock ordering is a good tool to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: @R..: do you see an example where my last algo would fail?

Comment: Indeed, your algorithm fills in some of the details @Adam left out.. :-) But I'm beginning to doubt either works. Something must happen between steps 3 and 4 (the time where **no lock** is held) to ensure that `p` does not become invalid. Otherwise the attempt to lock `p` is memory corruption. Keeping the lock on `c` would accomplish that, but breaks the algorithm. Would it work with more fine-grained locks?

Comment: @R..: IMHO you have no other option as to implement a kind of refcounting on the list items. Otherwise you can never be sure that the item to which you've got a pointer will not be already deallocated at the time you try to delete it.

Comment: @R..: So, with refcounting between the steps 3 and 4 the both items *p and *c are guaranteed alive (not deallocated), but they may be removed from the list before the step 4. Refcounting ensures that the removal from list but holding a reference won't lead to a problem accessing *p.

Comment: @R..: in fact my algo is not inspired by Adam's idea, lock ordering is a common technique for avoiding deadlocks.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to imply that it was. Yours was posted first anyway. I just later realized that yours was a more detailed version of what Adam was proposing.

Comment: I might be able to do the refcounting if the possible values of the reference count are only 0, 1, and 2 (which they seem to be) but otherwise I'm just about out of bits...

Comment: @R..: I think there's no way to protect the list items from being deallocated with only locking. Consider what would happen if we try to have during the deletion always at least one lock. At the beginning, definitely c must be locked. Imagine that at the same moment p is locked by some other thread trying to remove p (p is c->prev). Now, you need to lock both prev and next of c (still holding the lock to c) in order to proceed. The same thing must be done by the second thread holding the lock of p, so we are going to have a deadlock. Well, it's not a valid proof, maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: @R..: (1) can you guarantee that the only one thread will have the pointer to any c and try to delete it? Otherwise we are going to have 1000 threads and therefore 1000 refs hanging between the steps 3 and 4 (imagine that all 1000 threads are preempted after step 3 and wait for a long time).

Comment: @R..: (2) maybe you can have the refcounts external to the list? Only the references that are external w.r.t. the list are interesting.

Comment: Yes, only one thread will have the pointer to `c` and try to remove it from the list (it's already locked `c` for its own use at this point, and will make use of `c` after removing it from the list). Therefore I think the number of references is bounded by 2 or perhaps 3 (if both neighbors are being removed).

Comment: As for your comments about deadlock above, I wonder if there's a way that the threads removing items could cooperate instead of waiting on the locks. If one thread could traverse the locked-for-removal portion of the list and obtain locks on the elements prev/next to that whole portion of the list, it could do the removal for all the others. What I don't know how to do though is keep the threads from fighting over who gets to do that. Maybe it's as simple as `if (prev_already_locked_for_removal) wait...`

Comment: @R..: if we don't count the links from the item's neighbours in the list, the maximal refcount should be 2 (working with c->next doesn't require increasing the refcount as all the access is done only under the lock). However we need one more bit for marking if the item is a part of the list. Well, maybe we can avoid using this bit by just checking prev/next for null.

Comment: @R..: the cooperation between the threads seems to be really tricky. We don't know the exact moment when c->prev will be removed if it's already_locked_for_remove, so we don't know when we may update the new c->prev's value...

Answer (score 5):

Please don't take this answer harshly, but don't do this.

You will almost certainly wind up with bugs, and very hard bugs to find at that. Use the pthreads lock primitives. They are your friends, and have been written by people who deeply understand the memory model provided by your processor of choice. If you try to do the same thing with CAS and atomic increment and the like, you will almost certainly make some subtle mistake that you won't find until it's far too late.

Here's a little code example to help illustrate the point. What's wrong with this lock?

```
volatile int lockTaken = 0;

void EnterSpinLock() {
  while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&lockTaken, 0, 1) { /* wait */ }
}

void LeaveSpinLock() {
  lockTaken = 0;
}
```

The answer is: there's no memory barrier when releasing the lock, meaning that some of the write operations executed within the lock may not have happened before the next thread gets into the lock. Yikes! (There are probably many more bugs too, for example, the function doesn't do the platform-appropriate yield inside the spin loop and so is hugely wasteful of CPU cycles. &c.)

If you implement your double-linked list as a circular list with a sentinal node, then you only need to perform two pointer assignments in order to remove an item from the list, and four to add an item. I'm sure you can afford to hold a well-written exclusive lock over those pointer assignments.

Note that I am assuming that you are not one of the few people who deeply understand memory models only because there are very few of them in the world. If you are one of these people, the fact that even you can't figure it out ought to be an indication of how tricky it is. :)

I am also assuming that you're asking this question because you have some code you'd actually like to get working. If this is simply an academic exercise in order to learn more about threading (perhaps as a step on your way to becoming a deep low-level concurrency expert) then by all means, ignore me, and do your research on the details of the memory model of the platform you're targeting. :)

Comment: +1 because with answers like that you shouldn't have just 1 rep. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid deadlock if you maintain a strict hierarchy of locks: if you're locking multiple nodes, always lock the ones closer to the head of the list first.  So, to delete an element, first lock the node's predecessor, then lock the node, then lock the node's successor, unlink the node, and then release the locks in reverse order.

This way, if multiple threads try to delete adjacent nodes simultaneously (say, nodes B and C in the chain A-B-C-D), then whichever thread first gets the lock to node B will be the one that will unlink first.  Thread 1 will lock A, then B, then C, and thread 2 will lock B, then C, then D.  There's only competition for B, and there's no way that thread 1 can hold a lock while waiting for a lock held by thread 2 and while thread 2 is waiting on the lock held by thread 1 (i.e. deadlock).

Comment: I like this. It's simple and I think it meets the requirements. I do have to make a secondary lock for node-as-member-of-list (since as I described in other comments, the existing lock for the current node is already held and can't be released at removal-time), but otherwise it seems straightforward to implement this.

Comment: The problem is this: Given node C how to you get and lock B without locking C first? Right after reading C.prev some other thread might change it and delete B and then you have an dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get away without a lock for the whole list.  Here's why:

**Insert into an Empty List**

Threads A and B wants to insert an object.

Thread A examines the list, finds it empty

A context switch occurs.

Thread B examines the list, finds it empty and updates the head and tail to point to its object.

A context switch occurs

Thread A updates the head and tail to point to its object.  Thread B's object has been lost.

**Delete an item from the middle of the list**

Thread A wants to delete node X.  For this it first has to lock X's predecessor, X itself and X's successor since all of these nodes will be affected by the operation.  To lock X's predecessor you must do something like

```
spin_lock(&(X->prev->lockFlag));
```

Although I've used function call syntax, if `spin_lock` is a function, you are dead in the water because that involves at least three operations before you actually have the lock:

- place the address of the lock flag on the stack (or in a register)
- call the function
- do the atomic test and set

There are two places there where thread A can be swapped out and another thread can get in and remove X's predecessor without thread A knowing that X's predecessor has changed.  So you have to implement the spin lock itself atomically.  i.e. you have to add an offset to X to get x->prev then dereference it to get *(x->prev) and add an offset to that to get lockFlag and then do an atomic operation all in one atomic unit.  Otherwise there is always an opportunity for something to sneak in after you have committed to locking a particular node but before you have actually locked it.

Comment: @JeremyP: re: insert into an empty list. The thread A must first lock the head, then examine it and update, and only than unlock. This way we don't have the problem which you describe.

Comment: @Vlad: Indeed. Or just make the head and tail permanent nodes (possibly the same node) to eliminate the special casing.

Comment: @R..: indeed, head and tail must be permanent. I would however avoid having them the same node, because locking the head will implicitly lock the tail, so this will break the lock ordering. (Consider the case of list with just head, tail, two items and two threads trying to remove those items simultaneously.)

Comment: @R.. @Vlad: If you make the head and tail permanent nodes and you always have to lock them then you are creating a single list wide lock - well two.  And you still haven't solved the race condition on delete.

Comment: Or on insert at the end.  You need to lock the node in front of the tail and between deciding what that node is and locking it, there is always an opportunity for it to disappear.

Comment: You need to lock them on the *first* insertion (and with my access pattern, you need to lock the tail on all insertions), but I haven't seen any argument that you have to lock them when removing an element from the interior of the list. That's one of my 3 operations on the list, and probably a good half of the operations on the list are of that type.

Comment: @R..: But as I explained in my answer, there is a race condition on deletions from the interior of the list.  You first have to locate the address of the lock flag in the previous node, then you have to apply the lock.  Between those two operations, another thread can delete the previous node.  The same issue applies to insertions at the end.

Comment: What if a node cannot be removed while its neighbors are locked? (Possibly with a second lock, not the same lock.)

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll have to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I note that the only reason you need a doubly-linked list here is because of the requirement to delete nodes from the middle of the list, that were obtained without walking the list.  A simple FIFO can obviously be implemented with a singly-linked list (with both head and tail pointers).

You could avoid the deletion-from-the-middle case by introducing another layer of indirection - if the list nodes simply contain a `next` pointer and a `payload` pointer, with the actual data pointed to elsewhere (you say memory allocation is not possible at the point of insertion, so you'll just need to allocate the list node structure at the same point that you allocate the payload itself).

In the delete-from-the-middle case, you simply set the `payload` pointer to `NULL` and leave the orphaned node in the list.  If the FIFO pop operation encounters such an empty node, it just frees it and tries again.  This deferral lets you use a singly-linked list, and a lockless singly-linked list implementation is significantly easier to get right.

Of course, there is still an essential race here around the removal of a node in the middle of the queue - nothing appears to stop that node coming to the front of the queue and being removed by another thread before the thread that has decided it wants to remove it actually gets a chance to do so.  This race appears to be outside the scope of the details provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas.

First, to avoid the deadlock problem I would do some sort of spinlock:

- lock the item that is to be deleted
- try to lock one of the neighbors, if you have cheap random bits available chose the side randomly
- if this doesn't succeed abandon your first lock
  and loop
- try to lock the other one
- if this succeeds delete your item
- else abandon both locks
  and loop

Since splicing an element out of a list is not very lengthy as an operation, this shouldn't cost you much performance overhead. And in case that you really have a rush to delete all elements at the same time, it still should give you some good parallelism.

The second would be to do lazy delete. Mark your elements that are to be deleted and only remove them effectively when they appear at the end of the list. Since you are only interested in the head and the tail the effective users of the list items can do this. The advantage is that when they are at the end when deleted, the deadlock problem disappears. The disadvantage is that this makes the final deletion a sequential operation.

Comment: Lazy delete is not possible; it would lead to memory corruption because as soon as the node is pulled from the list, the memory that was storing prev/next pointers is committed to a different use.

Comment: What if you abandon your first lock and then some other thread deletes the item. Then you have a dangling pointer to the item and are trying to lock it.